# Using Maven to run a remote command

Tags: java, maven-2

What is the best way to have Maven execute a command on a remote server?

Before I use a wagon to move my newly created jar to our development environment, I want to shut down a service that depends on it.

The best I can come up with so far is to use the exec-maven-plugin to execute the remote command via ssh. Is there are better/more preferred way to do this?

Comment: Not exactly maven, but we use Hudson (which can run maven jobs). Hudson can control remote nodes - execute builds on them or just run arbitrary commands. Works very well.

Comment: ssh works for this kind of thing; since we're using Python anyway we use Fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.2/

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Maven doesn't provide any particular support to execute ssh commands. So either use the [Maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) or the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and the SSHEXEC Ant task if portability is a concern.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I figured, but I wanted some confirmation from the community since I'm knew to Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sshexec-maven-plugin.

More info:

- [wiki](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Sshexec-maven-plugin)
- [source](https://github.com/evgeny-goldin/maven-plugins/tree/master/sshexec-maven-plugin)